# How to select any full column except the header?

Tags: vba, excel, range

This was the hardest thing for me to figure out, this is after sifting through stack overflow for 4hrs without results.

This wont care if you have blank rows and it won't delete your header.

This is a simple solution.

```
Call RangeA2SelectandClear     
Call RangeB2SelectandClear     
Call RangeC2SelectandClear    
Call RangeD2SelectandClear
```

Call like above

And subs below.

```
Sub RangeA2SelectandClear()
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).ClearContents
End Sub

Sub RangeB2SelectandClear()
Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 2)).ClearContents
End Sub

Sub RangeC2SelectandClear()
Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(Rows.Count, 3)).ClearContents
End Sub

Sub RangeD2SelectandClear()
Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(Rows.Count, 4)).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Edit "more ways of doing things like so:"

incase it doesnt select your range.

```
Range(Cells(2, ColNum), Cells(Rows.Count, ColNum).End(xlUp))
```

to select a row of cells in (counting columns instead of counting rows)

```
Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Select
```

to select a range of columns excluding the header use like this:

```
Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Select
```

or *updated 10-22-15

```
Range("A7", Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).Select
```

The following selects a range in another sheet, but you technically cant select a range in another sheet so i just use a specific action that i want for the selection. This makes the code faster if i use it this way.
*updated 10-22-15

```
With Worksheets("Template BOM").Range(Worksheets("Template BOM").Cells(7, "A"), Worksheets("Template BOM").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlDown))
    'updated 10-22-15 there is no limit to the range now.
        '.Select 'if using .select this code fails.
        .ClearContents
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    End With
```

Comment: You'll need 16384 separate procedures to account for each column using that method.

Comment: the issue is when you are only using column A through D for the range and need the header to remain. there are so much complicated solutions out there. This was a done deal for me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is my GoTo for Answers. I'm sure a lot of people feel this way.

Comment: use this to count range in rows: Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Select

Comment: Hey guys, i updated more ways of doing a Range Search. In my opinion the last one updated 10-22-15 has the fastest way of doing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it not be better to have one procedure that works on any column rather than a procedure for each column?

```
Sub Test()

    Call ColumnSelectAndClear(1)
    Call ColumnSelectAndClear(2)
    ColumnSelectAndClear 3

End Sub

Public Sub ColumnSelectAndClear(ColNum As Long)

    With ActiveSheet
        .Range(.Cells(2, ColNum), .Cells(Rows.Count, ColNum)).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: this i like... Now what is ColumnSelectAndClear 3 for?... never mind i see what you are doing & you had a typo.

Comment: I did?  Thought I'd tested it.    Was just showing `ColumnSelectAndClear 3` to show that the procedure can be called without the `Call` keyword - no need for the brackets when calling that way.

Comment: Hey, Got it. Thank you for making this.

Comment: hey just ran into this, the color index wouldnt clear. so i added this:

.Range(.Cells(2, ColNum), .Cells(Rows.Count, ColNum)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

Comment: i was scratching my head for the longest period of time. We forgot .End(xlup) in the line: like this: .Range(.Cells(2, ColNum), .Cells(Rows.Count, ColNum).End(xlUp))

Comment: just so you will be aware; this is something i use on all my projects. You saved me a boat load of years of experience with this shortcut. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
Dim myRange As Range: Set myRange = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Rows("2:65536"))
myRange.ClearContents
```

Comment: but i have had sheets freeze when they try to count that many rows. This is with workbooks with 20+ sheets. I dont know if i like that solution.

Comment: The function doesn't count rows. It is a stated range that you are using as an overlay/mask on the UsedRange. The resultant range will give the UsedRange excluding the first row of the workbook as desired in the question...

Comment: Hey sorry didnt know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Call RangeA2SelectandClear

```
Sub RangeA2SelectandClear()
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).ClearContents
End Sub
```